# Why is there no back button in my view with using NavigationLink?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui-navigationlink

Below is my code which has 4 VStacks which I want to be clickable to take me to my next view:

```
ForEach (data) { order in
                        NavigationLink(destination: OrderDetailView(typeof: order.title)){
                            VStack(spacing: 32){
                                HStack {
                                    Text(order.title)
                                        .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .bold))
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                                    
                                }
                                ZStack {
                                    
                                    Circle()
                                        .trim(from: 0, to:1)
                                        .stroke(order.color.opacity(0.05),lineWidth: 10)
                                        .frame(width: ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 150) / 2), height: ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 150) / 2))
                                    
                                    Circle()
                                        .trim(from: 0, to: (order.totalcount/tcount))
                                        .stroke(order.color, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round))
                                        .frame(width: ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 150) / 2), height: ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 150) / 2))
                                    
                                    Text(getPercent(current: order.totalcount, max: tcount) + " %")
                                        .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .bold))
                                        .foregroundColor(order.color)
                                        .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
                                    
                                }
                                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                                
                                Text("Total count: " + getDec(val: order.totalcount))
                                    .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .bold))
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                            }
                            .padding()
                            .background(.white)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                            .shadow(color: Color.white.opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x:0, y: 0)
                        }
```

Everything works fine and the transition takes place but there is no back button for me to come back to my original view. NavigationLink works fine in other parts of the code but not here, not sure why.

Comment: It is best to show a minimal reproducible code, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: Found the issue, just realized that I shouldn't use navigationLink without NavigationView